# stdClass Object foreach PHP loop

Tags: php, foreach

Been searching for a solution for my problem. Seams meny has the same q as me, but still haven't got a solution for my problem.

I have a stdClass Object that needs to be printed out in a foreach or somlike like that.
Here is a cut of the result i get with a "print_r($result)".

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [itemDescription] => I
            [itemImage] => 2131099833
            [itemName] => ABOOD
            [itemPrice] => 8
            [itemQuantity] => 1
            [itemUid] => 1007
            [orders] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date_created] => 0
                    [id] => 1
                    [ordered] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [itemDescription] => 
            [itemImage] => 2131099833
            [itemName] => PAPAYA
            [itemPrice] => 8
            [itemQuantity] => 1
            [itemUid] => 1010
            [orders] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date_created] => 0
                    [id] => 1
                    [ordered] => 
                )

        )

)


    foreach ($result as  $value)
{
    foreach ($value as  $key=>$value1)
{
    if($key=="itemUid")
    {
    echo $value1;
    }


    if($key=="itemQuantity")
    {
    echo $value1;
    }

}
}
```

any easy method

Comment: I guess a recursive function would work.

Comment: You don't actually have an object, you have an array of objects. What have you tried to print out what you want? What is your expected result?

Comment: Have you tried `get_object_vars ` https://www.php.net/get-object-vars to get the array of properties and their values?

Comment: What is your question? Please edit your request to include a question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for each stdClass object in your array:

```
foreach ($stdClassObject as $propName => $propValue) {
    echo $propName . '->' . $propvalue;
}
```

As @arzhed stated in the comments, it's not necessary to use get_object_vars to iterate over the properties of an stdClass object.

Comment: The use of get_object_vars is unnecessary. As stated by the doc, "foreach works only on arrays and objects" https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php . Try it out

Comment: Cool, didn't know that, will update the answer. Thanks!